# wget to fetch file URL's Instead of downloading them

Tags: linux, wget

I'm using `wget` to download files, but rather than downloading them, I want to print the URL's of the files instead.

Here is what I'm currently doing right now,

```
wget example.com -l 30 -r -A .ico -U "Moz" robots=off
```

Comment: Use curl instead of wget and parse the output.